# Query a list of list of objects in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get all the details of a specific client: 
I have a list of list for the details of all the clients:

```
List<List<ClienteDetails>> _listaClientDetails = List<List<ClienteDetails>> ();
```

I want to get the details for a specific client, and I'm trying to do it by using this code: I

```
var result = _listaProductosFactura.where((detailsList) => detailsList.where((cliente) => cliente.id == id)).toList();
```

But this code is wrong. "The return type 'Iterable' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context."

Does someone know what would be the right code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that this part of it doesn't return a boolean value :

detailsList.where((cliente) => cliente.id == id)

it returns an iterable from your inner list which is not a boolean.
So the first "where" method cannot return an iterable as it doesn't have a boolean result

```
var result = _listaProductosFactura.where((detailsList) => //you must have a boolean result here not an iterable 
//but detailsList.where((cliente) => cliente.id == id) gives you an iterable
```

You can do something like this to get the result you want:

```
List<List<ClienteDetails>> _listaClientDetails = List<List<ClienteDetails>> ();
var result;

  for(List<ClienteDetails> clienteDetails in _listaClientDetails){
    result =  clienteDetails.where((cliente)=>cliente.id == id).toList();
//goes through the inner list and get the element where cliente.id == id

  }
```